# Swift equivalent of C gmtime?

Tags: swift, date

Migrating a C code to Swift, what would be the equivalent code for that?

```
time(&CurrentTime);
tm = gmtime(&CurrentTime);
dayOfYear = tm->tm_yday + 1;
st = tm->tm_hour + tm->tm_min / 60.0 + tm->tm_sec / 3600.0;
```

I currently converted it to the following but I guess something is wrong (probably the start of time?):

```
let currentTime = Date()

let calendar = Calendar.current

let hour    = calendar.component(.hour,   from: currentTime)
let min     = calendar.component(.minute, from: currentTime)
let sec     = calendar.component(.second, from: currentTime)

let dayOfYear = Double(calendar.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for: currentTime)!) + 1

let hHour     = Double(hour)
let hMin      = Double(min) / 60.0
let hSec      = Double(sec) / 3_600.0
```

Comment: What specifically is going wrong? What are you looking to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you *can* call those C library functions from Swift:

```
var currentTime = time(nil)
let tm = gmtime(&currentTime).pointee

let dayOfYear = tm.tm_yday + 1
let st = Double(tm.tm_hour) + Double(tm.tm_min) / 60.0 + Double(tm.tm_sec) / 3600.0
```

`gmtime()` converts the time value without time zone adjustment.
In order to get the same results with `Calendar`
you'll have to set its time zone to GMT:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
```

The return value of `calendar.ordinality(of:...)` is one-based,
so you must not add `1`:

```
let dayOfYear = calendar.ordinality(of: .day, in: .year, for:  currentTime)!
```

Finally, you can retrieve multiple date components with a single call:

```
let comps = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: currentTime)
let st = Double(comps.hour!) + Double(comps.minute!)/60 + Double(comps.second!)/3600
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to get the floating point number of hours since the start of day (GMT). You can also achieve this with:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)!
let now = Date()
let startOfDay = calendar.startOfDay(for: now)
let hours = now.timeIntervalSince(startOfDay) / 60 / 60
```